# Zend_Session_Namespace from non-Zend PHP

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

I need to integrate my no-framework code with my brand new Zend Application. But they need to share a session. The problem I am facing is - when I am setting the session variables from the non-zend php using

```
$_SESSION['MyApp']['user']=$user;
```

I cant access the session from the Zend Application, i tried both -

```
print_r($_SESSION['MyApp']['user']);
```

and

```
$myAppSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('MyApp');
print_r($myAppSession->user);
```

Doesn't work. Info - I have

```
resources.session.name = "MyApp"
```

in my bootstrap ini file.

Comment: Might be influenced by your app's namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way out, Zend Session has a different session id than normal PHP sessions, so what I did was to send the session id from zend with the request and start the session with that session id -

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['sess_id'])) {
        $sess_id = $_REQUEST['sess_id'];
    }

    session_id($sess_id);
    session_start();
```

Its not beautiful code, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Session_Namespace is just a wrapper for $_SESSION so this should be straightforward. When you say it doesn't work, is the $_SESSION array empty? If so, make sure you are creating the sessions in the same way (i.e. using the same session storage, cookie name etc.).

Comment: yeah, its empty...shud be straight forward...should i use a session_start() in the non-zend php?

Comment: @Nandini Yes, in order to use `$_SESSION` in the non-ZF app, you need to execute `session_start()` prior to its use

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing session name with ZF session namespaces.

The session name refers to the value stored in the session cookie and does not have any effect on the actual contents of `$_SESSION`.

For your apps to share a session, they both need to set the same name using [`session_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) or the [`session.name`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) php.ini directive.

Comment: made it like session_name('Cellthis'); session_start(); $_SESSION['user'] = $user; Doesn't work...

Comment: @Nandini Why "Cellthis"? Isn't your ZF session name "MyApp"?